# getting key_string_value using content delivery api

Tags: content-delivery

I need to retrieve the key_string_value based on value of key_name. The code i am using is as below.

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
  Query query;
  CustomMetaKeyCriteria metaKeyCriteria = new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("page_title", Criteria.Equal);

  query=new Query( CriteriaFactory.And(pubCriteria,metaKeyCriteria));
  var j = query.ExecuteEntityQuery();
}
```

The list of items that i get after executing this query doesnot contains any property to fetch the key value and hence i will have to individuall call getmeta on each item id and fetch the value. Is there any alternate way using which i can get the values(to avoid so many calls to database as i believe each getmeta will hit the db)

Regards,
Rajendra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**WARNING: there is not way to get what you are seeking. You can only get the metadata objects but these do not contain connected entities (CustomMeta or RelatedKeywords). If you're interested only in the properties of resulted items then you can use the following approach**

When using the Broker Query API and calling the `ExecuteEntityQuery` method you get the metadata objects (with no connected entities). Example:

```
Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.IItem[] results = query.ExecuteEntityQuery();
CustomMeta customMeta = null;

for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
{
    Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.IItem itm = results[i];
    if (itm is IComponentMeta)
    {
        IComponentMeta cm = (IComponentMeta)itm;
        customMeta = cm.CustomMeta;
    } 
    else if (itm is IPageMeta)
    {
        IPageMeta pm = (IPageMeta)itm;
        customMeta = pm.CustomMeta;
    } 
    else if (itm is IKeywordMeta)
    {
        IKeywordMeta km = (IKeywordMeta)itm;
        customMeta = km.CustomMeta;
    }
    else if (itm is ITemplateMeta)
    {
        ITemplateMeta tm = (ITemplateMeta)itm;
        customMeta = tm.CustomMeta;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already tried with IPageMeta but the custommeta is coming with 0 children, but if i use get meta i get the required name value collection

Comment: you're right. Looking closely at the API, that method does not load the CustomMeta or the RelatedKeywords. You will need to manually get it by yourself.

Comment: I have checked with sql profiler and its executing queryies for all the items to fetch metadata. The only thing is i am not able to fetch it from the api.

Comment: because i am getting 367 rows after executing and if i have to call getmeta for each it will hugely impact the performance

Comment: what if you enable caching for "Metadata"? That should help you a lot. You can combine this approach with calling the method ExecuteQuery which is a lot less demanding to the database.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the reply, I have never implemented caching for metadata, could you please give me a pointer to any resource which i can check. Also is it possible to apply caching to metadata only?

Comment: In the cd_storage_conf.xml add this inside ItemTypes tag: <Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="true" storageId="myStorageId"/> (change the storageId to your own). You also need to have this <ObjectCache Enabled="true">. But you also need to read the on-line docs about Caching to see how you need to set-up cache channel service (if needed).

Comment: +1, Daniel. The last two comments would make a good separate question and answer on metadata caching. Rajendra, care to start a separate question for it?